# How to build X509Chain in Azure Function?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, x509certificate2

Normally, I put trusted certificates (root and intermediate) in a local store on a Windows machine and X509Chain is built. But in Azure Functions there are no "local stores". How to build chain then?

This question is not related to SSL/TLS certificates, nor to web sites or web services. It is about any arbitrary certificate and arbitrary trusted root and intermediate certificates, not published by any well-known certification authority. I have a business rule that every certificate that was used to sign a document shall descend from a given root via given intermediate.

Thank you in advance -